# Video from Youtube API does not play onClick

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm not sure exactly why but for some reason my videos do not seem to play when clicked. Instead they queue in the player but do not play. Has anyone experienced this before or have any idea how the issue can be resolved?

Source:

```
public class Home extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,
YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener {

    public static final String API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "o7VVHhK9zf0";
    public static final String VIDEO1_ID = "xVHHJqntuXI";
    public static final String VIDEO2_ID = "YWteQj_q3Ro";
    public static final String VIDEO3_ID = "83ZgtqTw-mI";
    public static final String VIDEO4_ID = "n5wMza29JwI";
    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView1;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView2;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView3;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView4;
    private String[] drawerListViewItems;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerListView;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader;
    ScrollView mainScrollView;
    Button fav_up_btn1;
    Button fav_dwn_btn1;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);


        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        // get list items from strings.xml
        drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);

        // get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
        drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
                drawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
                );
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        mainScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.groupScrollView);

        youTubeThumbnailView1 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview1);
        youTubeThumbnailView1.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        fav_up_btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn1);

        fav_up_btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean favIsUp = fav_up_btn1
                        .getBackground()
                        .getConstantState()
                        .equals(getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.fav_up_btn1).getConstantState());
                // set the background
                fav_up_btn1
                .setBackgroundResource(favIsUp ? R.drawable.fav_dwn_btn1
                        : R.drawable.fav_up_btn1);
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView2 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview2);
        youTubeThumbnailView2.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO2_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView3 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview3);
        youTubeThumbnailView3.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO3_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView4 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview4);
        youTubeThumbnailView4.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO4_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

        youTubePlayer = player;

        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
            YouTubeInitializationResult error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
            YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader) {

        youTubeThumbnailLoader = thumbnailLoader;
        thumbnailLoader
        .setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailLoadedListener());

        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VIDEO_ID);

    }

    private final class ThumbnailLoadedListener implements
    YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, ErrorReason arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, String arg1) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // call ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(), if it returns
        // true
        // then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
youTubePlayer.play();
```

With

```
youTubePlayer.loadVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
```